# Gnome Shell menus behind the panel

Tags: gnome, firefox, menu, command-line

In Gnome Shell when i right click to open the content menu for Firefox and some other applications, some of the objects are behind the top panel and i have to scroll down and click again to see the top objects. Is this a bug or by design? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, please?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question:

With the default font sizes if the context menu is big it moves some times behind the panel but you must have small screen like my screen with 1024x768 resolution. I think this is a bug. I can find bug reports from over a year but the problem is still there. The problem affects and other software with long context menus.